# Python dictionary issue- different output with each run (with dictionary input, works fine with a list)?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-else

I'm new to python (and stackoverflow) and have written this short piece of code which declares "suitable for vegetarians" depending on the values of the dictionary, or "not suitable for vegetarians" should something non-veggie be encountered (i.e. bacon).
I've included a print statement after break to test that break works correctly, so that when bacon is encountered, the for loop stops and 'else' is also inhibited.
My issue is that each time I build and run this code in Sublime, I get a different output. When running it on the Codecademy online IDE, depending on the key for "mushrooms", it will either print this inappropriately (say with key "3") or will not print (as expected) with key "4".
I've changed the dictionary to a list and the code functions correctly, but this issue persists when using a dictionary- I can't figure out the reason for this, so any help would be great!

```
breakfast = {"1": "eggs", "2": "bacon", "3": "mushrooms", "4": "bread", "5": "tomatoes"}

for item in breakfast:
  if breakfast[item] == "bacon":
    print ("Not suitable for vegetarians")
    break
  print (item, breakfast[item])
else:
  print ("Suitable for vegetarians!")
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: what is the purpose of your code. Do you think your code is correct?

Comment: The purpose is to loop through the dictionary values and if, in this instance, if bacon is encountered, the code breaks and "not suitable for vegetarians" is declared (which is the case so the code is correct). The print statement after the break was for me to test how the break is working as the for loop goes over the items (keys) in the dictionary, and curiously, i get this varying output.

Comment: for same input you getting the different output each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries in Python are unordered when using Python <= 3.5
That means you arent guaranteed to get they keys in any particular order when you loop over them.

What Python version are you using?

Comment: This makes sense! And given that the codecademy python I'm using is written in python 2 and for Sublime Python 3.5.2, this may account for the difference in output between the two.

Comment: That is probably the reason yes.